# How can I use Google Maps with Processing?

Tags: google-maps, processing

I want to use Google Maps API with Processing. Until now I was just able to get Google Places  data, but I'm struggling with the map itself. I know about other map options, like unfold or modestMaps, but I need Google. In particular because of the directions API in further progress. I've searched this forum and the web, without any help. I thought it should be quite
easy.

How can I use Google Maps with Processing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about getting a full featured, dynamic Google Maps within your Processing app, but you might be able to modify the Processing library for the Google Weather API to instead use the Directions or Static Maps APIs.  http://www.onformative.com/lab/google-weather-library-for-processing/

If you download the source and check out GoogleWeather.java you can see the constructor is calling the WeatherAPI and getting back the XML result.  I think you could do the same thing except use the Directions API in it's place.

Here's a post on a Java blog about showing Static Maps API results in Java, which might be translatable into Processing: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cajo/archive/2010/10/16/adding-google-maps-your-java-application

For something more dynamic, you might be able to adapt JXMapViewer, check out this article: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html